# Spring request scoped bean internals

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-ioc

I have been using request scoped beans for my application and I'm curious to know how spring stores those kind of beans in the application context? is there a http reuqest id linked to it? any help/documentation is most welcomed as I did not find much about it.

Answer (score 3):

Each [`Scope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/Scope.html) is has its own implementation which knowns how and where objects are stored. The request scope, implemented by the [`RequestScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestScope.html), stores the object in the request attributes (see [sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestScope.java)).

What Spring does when it finds a scoped bean (i.e. bean with `@Scope` or specific annotation like `@RequestScope`, `@SessionScope`) is to create a proxy of that object. The proxy will do a lookup of the actual object instance (or create it and store it) using the earlier mentioned `Scope` instance. It will then pass on the method call to actual the instance.

You can check this by looking at an `@Autowired` scoped bean and you will see that it is actually a proxy instead of a real instance.

The current request is accessible in Spring through the [`RequestContextHolder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java).

Comment: would you happen to know where the bean look up code is in the spring git project? :)